# WPF tool kit vs Extended WPF tool kit

Tags: wpf

I'm new to WPF. I just want to know the difference between the WPF tool kit which was released in 2010 and the Extended WPF tool kit community edition released in 2015 . I know that both are open source. Should I go for the extended version since it's current. What's the difference between the two releases? Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question is too broad: it looks more like a request for review. Please narrow down it to the specific code issue you have experienced. Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wpf toolkit is obsolete and not maintained anymore. Extended wpf toolkit is its continuation from the community. You should go for Extended WPF Toolkit, if you actually need a toolkit.